# How to draw a star in P5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to make a class "star" with a method inside of it that, at given coordinates and size, draws a star. Something like rect() or ellipse() functions.

How can make it?

Answer (score 2):

The best advice I can give you is to get out a piece of paper and a pencil. Draw out the points of a star, and label their X and Y coordinates.

Then you can use something like the `line()` or `beginShape()` function to draw that on the screen using code.

You can find more info in [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Answer (score -1):

With the new update on p5 you can simply type `star(coordinates)` and then make the star.

Comment: Does such a function really exist? Perhaps you can back that up with documentation and example usage.